# How to create C program to determine lagest number by entered value?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I've created a program to determine largest number, but my lecturer says it isn't perfect, can anybody make it perfect?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main () {
     double a,b=0,n, i;
     printf("limit of n input: ");
     scanf ("%lf",&n);

     for (i=1;i<=n;i++) {
         scanf("%lf",&a);
         if (a>b) b=a;
     }

     printf("%.2lf", b);

     return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Add `\n` at end of each `printf` format string, or else call `fflush`. And `i` and `n` should probably be `int` not `double` ....

Comment: in what way is this imperfect? what is your lecturer looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it that way, sorry for the mass of text. I think it is coming from the typical Objective-C style programming with long words:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int clean_stdin() {
    while (getchar()!='\n');

    return 1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char c;
    signed int count = 0;    // number of numbers to scan

    unsigned int fireErrorMessage = 0;
    do {
        if (fireErrorMessage == 1) {
            printf("You entered not a positive natural number. Please enter a number >0 Examples: 1 22 4012\n"); // output for the user
        }
        if (fireErrorMessage == 0) {
            fireErrorMessage = 1;
        }
        printf("How many integers do you want to insert (Inser a number >0)? ");
    } while (((scanf("%d%c", &count, &c) != 2 || c != '\n') && clean_stdin()) || count < 1);

    signed int indexOfNumber; // for index, declared outside because of output at the end

    signed int highestNumberIndex;
    double highestNumber; // saving the highest value in a helper variable

    fireErrorMessage = 0;
    for (indexOfNumber = 1; indexOfNumber <= count; indexOfNumber++) {
        double scannedNumber;
        do {
            if (fireErrorMessage == 1) {
                printf("You entered not a number. Please enter a number. Examples: 3.0 -1 14\n"); // output for the user
            }
            if (fireErrorMessage == 0) {
                fireErrorMessage = 1;
            }
            printf("Input number %d: ", indexOfNumber); // output for the user
        } while (((scanf("%lf%c", &scannedNumber, &c) != 2 || c != '\n') && clean_stdin()));

        fireErrorMessage = 0;

        if (indexOfNumber == 1 || scannedNumber > highestNumber) {
            highestNumberIndex = indexOfNumber;
            highestNumber = scannedNumber;
        }
    }

    printf("Highest input number on index %d, the value is about %.2lf\n", highestNumberIndex, highestNumber);

    return 0;
}
```

### Output

```
How many integers do you want to insert (Inser a number >0)? aa5
You entered not a positive natural number. Please enter a number >0 Examples: 1 22 4012
How many integers do you want to insert (Inser a number >0)? -3
You entered not a positive natural number. Please enter a number >0 Examples: 1 22 4012
How many integers do you want to insert (Inser a number >0)? 3
Input number 1: aa
You entered not a number. Please enter a number. Examples: 3.0 -1 14
Input number 1: -50.0001
Input number 2: 51a
You entered not a number. Please enter a number. Examples: 3.0 -1 14
Input number 2: -1.00
Input number 3: -0.1
Highest input number on index 3, the value is about -0.10
```

Comment: And if count < 1, indexOfNumber is 1 and highestNumber in uninitialized.

Comment: Very good. Two suggested improvements: add `\n` at the end of the `printf` format string... and check that the `count` number given is > 0. The lecturer did want "perfect" after all.

Comment: And do some error checking on the `scanf` - if the input is a string of text, `scanf` will fail. You would want to trap that too. "Perfect" code checks ALL inputs.

Comment: don't  bother with unsigned especially got user input, there's nothing preventing user entering a negative count.

Comment: Ok changed it. After scanf a **\n** wasn't needed.

Comment: The only criticism the professor could now make is "you are making it too complicated." But I like it. The right answer got accepted...

Answer (score 2):

If by "not perfect" she meant "doesn't properly handle negative numbers or an empty set", then you'd want to

1. Treat n<1 as a special case (why should 0 be the largest of an empty set?)
2. Read the first number outside of the loop, so you're not making as assumption as to the smallest possible number

Comment: so, what should I do to declare smallest possible number? which variable have to I replace?

Comment: If you read in the first number outside the loop, you have a value that the answer can't possibly be less than.

Answer (score 1):

This code caters for negative, not a number input for the loop index as well as negative and not a number inputs inside the loop. Thanks

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <math.h>
  int main () {
             int n, i;
             double a,b=0;
             printf("limit of n input: ");
             scanf ("%lf",&n);

            if(n < 0){
                      printf("value of n cannot be negative");
                      return 0;
                     }
           else if (n == 0)
                     return 0;
           else if (isnan(n))
                     return 0;

           else{
             for (i=1;i<=n;i++) 
               {
                   scanf("%lf",&a);
                   if(!isnan(a) && a > 0)
                         { 
                          if (a>b) b=a;
                         }

               }
              printf("%.2lf", b);

              return 0;
               }
             }
```

Comment: What does this mean `!isnan(a) && a > 0`

Comment: This checks that 'a' is be a number (not a string) and greater than zero.  feel free to give an upvote if it helps you. thanks